# How to assign multi level Json data array to single Angular object?

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, controller, angular-ngmodel

I have a json data like below

```
{
  "data": {
    "points": 390,
    "medal": "gold",
    "activeGoals": [{
      "examType": full,
      "dateApplied": null,
      "status": "Active-GoodStanding",
      "term": 2,
      "amountPaid": 2500,
      "pointEarned": null,
      "examDetails": {
        "totalAmountPaid": 4500,
        "examDate": 1459449000000,
        "endDate": 1554057000000,
        "totalMarks": 100,
        "nextExamDate": 1493577000000,
        "interestRate": 0
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

In this Json data there is 'activeGoal' array,and inside of that there is an another array 'examDetails'

In Controller,I tried assigning these data into the angular object like below

```
  examCtrl.details ={};
  examCtrl.details =data;
  examCtrl.activeGoals=data.activeGoals;
  examCtrl.examDetails=data.activeGoals.examDetails;
```

I am getting activeGoals, but for examDetails I am getting 'undefined' error.
What is the wrong i am doing here??

Comment: activeGoals is an array. You should access it like data.activeGoals[1].examDetails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assign like this : `examCtrl.examDetails=data.activeGoals[0].examDetails;`

since `activeGoals` is itself an array and you need first index`([0])` value of it i.e., `examDetails`.

Further: as per your JSON `examDetails` is object not array.

Answer (score 0):

if you're confused what the exactly the data is you can always convert in JSON editor.then you can easily assign the object from JSON data.